# Positioning a <p> tag above canvas

Tags: html, css, position

Can someone help me figure out how to position the p tag "instructions" above my canvas? I need it to be centered, and to have it a little inside the top of the canvas. I cannot use canvas.strokeText for this, it has to be in html.

I have tried using different types and combinations of positions, margins, and z-indices, but everything I try either puts the text underneath the canvas or to the left or it. I need it hovering above the canvas (which is centered in the screen), or at the worst case, centered above the canvas.

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-colour: #87ceeb;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="positioned" id="instruct">
  <p class="positioned" style="text-align: center; top: 0px;" id="instructions"> Instructions </p>
</div>
<div id="canvas" class="positioned" style="position:absolute;">
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide idea or something like sketch of what you are trying to achieve? Because its unclear what you are trying to do, isn't 'instructions' already above the canvas. Also in order for the `canvas` in css to work you have to put `#` before it `#canvas` (as you are referencing to an id) and fix typo in `background-color`.

Comment: The text in the p tag is being displayed below the canvas. I want it to be displayed above the canvas (outside the bounds of the canvas), or superimposed on top of the canvas if possible (inside the bounds of the canvas)

Answer (score 0):

```css
canvas {
  border: 2px solid white;
  background-colour: #87ceeb;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 600px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
positioned {
  background-color: light grey;
   width: 300px;
    border: 5px solid balck;
      padding: 50px;
        margin: 20px;
         aligning: center
 }
```

```html
<div class="positioned" id="instruct">
  <p class="positioned" style="text-align: center; top: 0px;" id="instructions"> Instructions </p>
</div>
<div id="canvas" class="positioned" style="position:absolute;">
</div>
```

Comment: This is still positioning the instructions below the canvas

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, the canvas was being inserted into the document before document.body.childNodes[0] later in the script. Thanks for those who tried to help!